# Need the help with the recognition

Tags: discussion, scope

I am sorry for this question to be maybe off-top. I play piano a lot and I usually know how to play the music I hear. I heard one song a couple of times - but I only know that the text is in English and I could only play a bit of it.

Unfortunately, I do not know the website which can help me to recognize this song, so I only hope that someone from you can either recognize it or advise another website.

So my question is the following: if I can put a questions with a link to the music I played to ask someone to recognize this song?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for asking.  These are off-topic, yes.  Take a look at [this similar question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3425/which-song-is-mixed-in-within-sun-is-s) and my comment on it.  The main problems with these sort of questions are:

- They may be basic (if an answerer knows the song, there's no challenge in writing the name, and a layperson can identify a song just as well as an advanced musician)
- They may be uninteresting (if a user knows the answer it's simple, if they don't then it's irrelevant to them)
- It's too localized (the number of people trying to identify this particular song and who haven't found it through lyric searches is probably tiny, and they wouldn't be able to find your question through a search anyways)
- It doesn't really fit with our general scope — practice, performance, theory, history, composition, technique, and recording.  Identifying notes and intervals and playing by ear touches on many of those aspects, but identifying a song does not.

I'd encourage you to ask question like this in [the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/musical-practice-and-performance).  Anything to do with the site or at least tangentially related to music is on-topic there.

Comment: thanks, I asked it in chat.